# Limit of series for which both the number of terms and the function depend on $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have been trying to find the limit of the following series
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty} A_{n+1,i} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\binom{(n-1)m+i}{lm}(1-p)^{m(n-1)-lm+i}p^{lm}
\end{equation}
where $m\ge 2$, $1\le l \le m, 0<p<1$ and $m,l\in\mathbb{N}$. The reason I am trying to find the limit is to proof a more simple version of a question I previously posted ([Proof the distribution of the grouped values converges to the distribution of the samples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319192/proof-the-distribution-of-the-grouped-values-converges-to-the-distribution-of-th)), but for just two values. If my expression is right, I should find that if $\mathbb{P}(X_i = s_1) = p$, that the probability that we are sorting value $s_1$ for step $n+1$ (did not take $n$ so that the expression looks nicer) converges to $p$ as $n\to \infty$, so:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\hat{p}_{i,n+1} =  \lim_{n\to\infty}p\left(p^{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^m A_{n+1,i}\right) = p.
\end{equation}
Any advice on how to solve this limit or even an answer is really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

As the question is mainly about the limit I have left out how I found the expression, but I will add that if requested.

**Update**: A late update. Got my desired result using $m$ roots. Thanks

Comment: You can simplify by the change of variables $r = (1  - p)^m$ and $s = p^m$. It also looks like outside the stated range your terms are zero, just do the infinite sum. And you are picking each $m$-th term of the sum, the trick using $w_m$ an $m$-root of $1$ allows to isolate those. A true mess, but perhaps manageable...

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks, I'll try using m-roots and update when I'm done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
 A_{n,i} &= \frac{(1-p)^{m(n-1)+i}}{m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m(n-1)+i}\binom{m(n-1)+i}{k}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}w^{jk}\right)\\
 &= \frac{(1-p)^{m(n-1)+i}}{m}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(1+\frac{\omega^jp}{1-p})^{m(n-1)+i}\right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(1-p(1-\omega^j))^{m(n-1)+i}.
 \end{align}
    For $i = m$ we need to subtract the last term.
    \begin{align}
 A_{n,m} &= \frac{(1-p)^{mn}}{m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{mn}\binom{mn}{k}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}w^{jk}- m(\frac{p}{1-p})^{mn}\right)\\
 &= \frac{(1-p)^{mn}}{m}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(1+\frac{\omega^jp}{1-p})^{mn}- m(\frac{p}{1-p})^{mn}\right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{m}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(1-p(1-\omega^j))^{mn}-mp^{mn}\right).
 \end{align}
    Using these results we find
    \begin{align}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\hat{p}_{i,n+1} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}p(p^{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}A_{n,i} + A_{n,m})\\ 
 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(1-p(1-\omega^j))^{m(n-1)+i}.
 \end{align}
    As $|(1-p(1-\omega^j))|<1$ for $j\neq 0$ and is equal to $1$ for $j=0$, we find that all the terms, except for $j=0$, converge to 0.
    \begin{align}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\hat{p}_{i,n+1} = \frac{p}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m 1 = p.
 \end{align}